# WebApi OData: $filter 'any' or 'all' query not working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

First, using the ASP.NET WebApi tutorials I've created a basic [ApiController that exposes an Entity Framework model through OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options). The service works to return json for OData $filter queries.

When I perform OData [$filter queries that include "any" or "all"](http://www.odata.org/blog/2010/11/11/support-for-any-and-all) queryies on a multi-value property it throws an ODataException

Here's the OData query I'm trying to use

`~/api/Blogs?$filter=any(Tags,Name+eq+'csharp')`

My ApiController looks like this:

```
public class BlogController : ApiController
{
    public BlogsController()
    {
        this.Entities = new BlogEntities();
    }

    public ContactEntities Entities { get; set; }

    [Queryable(PageSize = 25, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable<Blog> Get()
    {
        return this.Entities.Blogs;
    }
}
```

The Blog entity has this contract

```
public Blog {
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Tag Tags { get; set; }
}

public Tag {
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The exception thrown

```
ODataException: Type 'Blog' does not have a property 'Name'
```

As you can see, I have nothing out of the ordinary in my code and everything should work fine. Is it possible that "any" and "all" queryies aren't supported yet in [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API OData](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData)?

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that the '$inlinecount' odata options gets ignored.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your any needs to be changed a bit. Try something like this:

```
~/api/Blogs?$filter=Tags/any(tag: tag/Name eq 'csharp')
```

This is assuming Tags actually returns a collection of Tags, not just a single Tag like you have above.

$inlinecount is only supported out of the box for the OData format. I wrote extensively about it here:

[Web API OData Inlinecount not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422831/web-api-odata-inlinecount-not-working/15422935)

The short answer is that you can get it working for other formats with code that looks like this:

```cs
public PageResult<Customer> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Customer> queryOptions)
{
    IQueryable results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(_customers.AsQueryable());
    return new PageResult<Customer>(results as IEnumerable<Customer>, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man!! After testing your suggestion, I looked at the OData specification... well let's just say I should have read that first.

Comment: The $inlinecount answer doesn't work for a service that inherits "ApiController"

Comment: I just tested it again- it works. Please include your code and the URL you used.

Comment: But ApiController has a Request property. You'll have to add a using for the System.Net.Http namespace to get the other methods.