# "Cannot support querying" Controller Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, odata, asp.net-web-api

I was working through the following answer found here: [Web API OData Inlinecount not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422831/web-api-odata-inlinecount-not-working/15422935)

Here is my controller, with some dummy data being served.

```
[Queryable]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public PageResult<Category> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Category> queryOptions)
    {
        var returnValue = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category() { Id = 1, Name= "Category 1"},
            new Category() { Id = 2, Name= "Category 2"},
            new Category() { Id = 3, Name= "Category 3"},
        };

        IQueryable results = queryOptions.ApplyTo(returnValue.AsQueryable());

        return new PageResult<Category>(results as IEnumerable<Category>,
            Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I try to do a get via Fiddler:

> "The action 'Get' on controller 'Values' with return type 'System.Web.Http.OData.PageResult`1[[ODataTest_Solution.DTO.Category, ODataTest Solution, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot support querying. Ensure the type of the returned content is IEnumerable, IQueryable, or a generic form of either interface."

If I change the method it to return an IQueryable, it obviously works just fine.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried your ValuesController and it works just fine.

Your problem is likely that you added the `[Queryable]` attribute to this action. If you use ODataQueryOptions, you don't need to use `[Queryable]` since you're applying the query yourself without the need for an action filter.

Comment: That was it. Changed the code example so that attribute is now included.