# Implementing ODataController with custom routing returns "The related entity set could not be found from the OData path" error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to move from our current implementation of ApiController to ODataController since it's the only way I found possible to enable returning OData Json formatted data. (Same with the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098505/odata-in-web-api-doesnt-follow-odata-standard-specs) but the solution didn't work for me)

I've been trying to workout ODataController and I found it working well enough following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/29/getting-started-with-asp-net-webapi-odata-in-3-simple-steps.aspx). However, my project implements a different routing from the default OData routing of the simple"~/odata/Entity". I need to group my controllers into areas since there are some controllers that duplicates in name.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111386/asp-net-webapi-generic-controller-for-odata-endpoint) and [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions#custom), I was able to implement custom routing and running it seems to reach the right controller and pass through it successfully. However, I still get an error in Fiddler of

> "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true;
>   charset=utf-8'."

with an inner exception of

> The related entity set could not be found from the OData path. The
>   related entity set is required to serialize the payload

and now I've been stuck for hours with it. Without the route handlers and simply accessing data through "~/odata/Entity", my code works well enough. It's just when I implement the custom routing that it fails after passing through my controller code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some code:

Global.asax:

```
            //Added this on App_Start
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomHttpControllerSelector(config)); 

            //Snippet from RegisterRoutes
            ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Entity>("Entities");
            IEdmModel model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

            config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
                routeName: "ODataDefault",
                routePrefix: "{version}/{area}/{controller}",     //Works since I could reach my controller
                model: model);
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public IQueryable<Entity> Get()
        {
            EntitySet entitySet = new EntitySet();
            return entitySet.Entities;
        }
```

CustomHttpControllerSelector:

Inheritted from [this](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/b397c84c62696ba5dafa8b524b0b90ae225c5468/src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerSelector.cs). Basically, this just parses the request to get the specific controller descriptor.

```
private HttpControllerDescriptor GetController(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor = null;

            IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();

            // Get variables from the route data.
            string versionName = null;
            routeData.Values.TryGetValue("version", out versionName );

            string areaName = null;
            routeData.Values.TryGetValue("area", out areaName);

            string controllerName = null;
            routeData.Values.TryGetValue("controller", out controllerName);

            string fullName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}.{2}", versionName, areaName, controllerName);

            // Search for the controller.
            // _controllerTypes is a list of HttpControllerDescriptors
            var type = _controllerTypes.Where(t => t.Key.EndsWith(fullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(t => t.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            if (type != null)
            {
                descriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, type);
            }

            return descriptor;
        }
```

Comment: Could you share a sample repro? Also, sharing the custom routing convention code too might help.

Comment: @RaghuRamNadiminti, thanks for replying. I edited some of my code with some the changes I made fumbling through this. I can't post all of my code though, it would be too long of a post but I added the new routing I implemented. Still can reach the exact method on the right controller but still an error when it gets back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually solved this just by removing the {controller} part of the routePrefix and implementing a custom **IODataRoutingConvention** to enter a default controller value when the initial parsing of the route doesn't detect a controller value. Code is as follows:

```
public string SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
     string controllerName = ""

     //do stuff here to select controller

     return controllerName;
}
```

I'm guessing this is the long substitute for the default and the contraints parameters in ApiController's map routing

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RouteName",
    routeTemplate: "{version}/{area}/{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = controllerName },
    constraints: new { version = v1 }
);
```

**Note:** Posting this as answer as of now but if anyone has a better explanation, I'll check it up. :)

Comment: This answer was helpful to me although i had a slightly different problem.  I wanted a context of the url (e.g. i want to know if a user was in a group based on the url) using the MapODataRoute and giving a routePrefix: "odata/{myKeyIWanted}" and then filtering it set me up to be able to push/pull values in from that location.  Thanks!